# on-premise to GCloud compute engine VPN using on-premise range IP

Tags: vpn, gcloud, nat

I have a compute engine with a service on it. This compute engine has an internal IP (10.208.0.X) and external IP and I can reach the service through external IP.

Now I want to create a VPN from on-premise to GCloud but I want that when I call the service from on-premise use and IP from on-premise range (172.30.XX) and be route to the compute engine.

I have configure the VPN between on-premise and gcloud using the next link:

https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/how-to/creating-static-vpns

- Created an VPC net and subnet using range 172.30.X.X
- Created an Classic VPN IKEv2 with Policy-based routing using the VPC net and subnet.
- Attached network tag to Compute engine and create a firewall rule allowing incoming trafic from on-premise.

  The VPN gateway and tunnel is up and running but I'm not able to reach compute engine neither using on-premise range (172.30.x.x) nor internal ip (10.208.0.X).

  Any help would be appreciated.

Regards

SOLVED:

Finally we have solved in that way.

- Created an VPC net and subnet using range 172.30.X.X. **OUR-NET**
- Create a Compute engine (CE) using **OUR-NET as primary interface eth0/nic0 and NOT External IP address**.
- Created an Classic VPN IKEv2 with Policy-based routing using the VPC net and subnet. https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/how-to/creating-static-vpns. At this point we are able to connect from our on-premise hosts to CE using **OUR-NET** range.
- Because our CE is in **OUR-NET and we haven't an external IP address** we have needed to enable Identity-Aware Proxy IAP for access through "gcloud compute ssh"
  https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/using-tcp-forwarding

thanks for the help.

Comment: 1. What kind of router do you have on premises? 2. Did you set up firewall rules on your router on premises? 3. it'll be helpful to find all the configuration commands and outputs in the question.

Comment: Hi Serhii, thanks for your response. I'm not aware about the information of the router on-premise, I'm configuring VPN only in gcloud side and testing from servers. When I review monitoring of the VPN tunnel in gcloud I see a peak on Received Bytes when I´m trying to connect to the VM in gcloud so seems that on-premise all is fine.

Comment: Are you able to ping from your VM in cloud internal router IP 172.30.X.X?